# ASP.NET MVC app works in debug but not when published using Plesk and GoDaddy

Tags: c#, asp.net, plesk

I have an MVC app that works perfectly in debug mode and testing, but after I publish using ftp to godaddy, the website opens up and works when toggling between the home page and the login page. If I try logging in I get an error or if I try using the search box on my homepage, I also get an error. Here is the screenshot: [image: Error]

After I log in or basically anything or than `'mydomain'.com/Home/Index/` I get this error, if I try `'mydomain'.com/Home/Search` or `'mydomain'.com/Search/Index` any other controller or action I get this. What could be the cause because I have tried everything? For example is HomeController/Search:

```
public ActionResult Search(string search, string searchlast)
    {
        var doctors = from d in db.Doctors
                      select d;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(search) || !String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchlast))
        {
            doctors = doctors.Where(d => d.FirstName.Contains(search) && d.LastName.Contains(searchlast));
            return View(doctors.ToList());
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

Here is Views/Home/Search which gives the error:

```
@model IEnumerable<Systemz.Models.Check>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Search";
}

<div class="jumbotron">
    <h2>Check</h2>
    <h4>Check for availability.</h4>
</div>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <p>
        First Name: @Html.TextBox("search") Last Name: @Html.TextBox("searchlast")
        <input type="submit" value="Search" name="search" />
        <a asp-action="Search" asp-controller="Home"></a>
    </p>
}

<table class="table table-hover dataTable">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <thead class="bd-dark white-text">
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Title:
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        First Name:
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Last Name:
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Address:
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Is Available?
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Address)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @if (item.IsAvailable == true)
                            {<p><a class="btn btn-success"></a></p> }
                            else
                            { <p><a class="btn btn-danger"></a></p>}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </div>
    </div>
</table>
```

Comment: You sure your database is uploaded to a place where your now online website can access it? Do you have your "PROD" database connection string correct?

Comment: I've tried changing my connection string over and over and nothing has helped. I have even tried different deploy methods (ftp, webdeploy) nothing has helped. Current connection string is `<add name="DbContextName" connectionString="Server=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`

Comment: Because the website opens up, could it be due to the routes? It goes between `AccountController.cs` and and `HomeController.cs` but using any actions other than `Index` on either controller gives the error page, and only those two controller work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from @Daniel Lorenz helped a bit, I originally thought it could be the `<connectionString/>` then I thought it could be routing when I posted the question, after the answer was posted I figured out it was the `<connectionString/>` and db update with the `DbContextName`. After getting the correct

```
<add name="DbContextName" connectionString="DataSource=ServerName;
    Integrated Security=False;Initial Catalog=DbName;User Id=username;
        Password=password;Encrypt=False;Packet Size=4096;" providerName=
            "System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Then in the Package Manager Console:

```
update-database -ConnectionStringName "DbContextName"
```

Then publish and all works well.

Answer (score 1):

You have to upload your database.  There is no such thing as (LocalDb) on your Godaddy hosted server.  You have to upload your database to Godaddy as well, figure out the connection string to that location, and then have that deploy correctly with your site.  If there isn't any firewalls in front of it, you can even test the connection to that database from your local machine.

Edit: And it isn't enough to just upload your database file.  You have to setup the database through their own tool so it attaches correctly and all that.

Comment: If im publishing using ftp wouldnt that upload the database as a file? I have tried using the ip address given on the plesk page but that didnt work either? How can I find the connection string to plesk? Is it somehting that I wuold have created

Comment: If you are using SQL Server, you have to go through GoDaddy's tool to setup the database - just like you would on SQL Server Management Studios.  You can't just upload the file by itself (as far as I know).

Comment: @janzen You can ask them about connection string that you need to use. For database, you need to create it via their control panel, and then restore your database via control panel or you can ask them to restore your db.